# Creating longitudinal datasets with reshape

Tags: r, reshape, data-manipulation

I have the dataset:

```
top100_repository_name  month   monthly_increase    monthly_begin_at    monthly_end_with
Bukkit                  2012-03 9                   431                 440
Bukkit                  2012-04 19                  438                 457
Bukkit                  2012-05 19                  455                 474
CodeIgniter             2012-03 15                  492                 507
CodeIgniter             2012-04 50                  506                 556
CodeIgniter             2012-05 19                  555                 574
```

I use the following R code:

```
library(reshape)
latent.growth.data <- read.csv(file = "LGC_data.csv", header = TRUE)
melt(latent.growth.data, id = c("top100_repository_name", "month"), measured = c("monthly_end_with"))
cast(latent.growth.data, top100_repository_name + month ~ monthly_end_with)
```

Which I want to use to create a dataset that has the following structure:

```
top100_repository_name    2012-03    2012-04    2012-05
Bukkit                    440        457        474
CodeIgniter               507        556        574
```

However, when I run my code I get the following output:

```
Using monthly_end_with as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

How can I modify my code so that I generate the desired output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my edit is correct, but please verify.

Comment: You need to do a couple of things: (i) save the result of the melt to an object, say `latent.growth.melt`, and then run the cast on `latent.growth.melt` per below. If you use the more recent reshape2 package (recommended), then use dcast() instead of cast() - the last line should then be something like `dcast(latent.growth.melt, top100_repository_name ~ month, value.var = "value")`. You can see why by looking at `latent.growth.melt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone will be along soon with a `plyr` solution i'm sure, but here is a base solution using the `reshape` function.

```
test <- read.table(textConnection("top100_repository_name  month   monthly_increase    monthly_begin_at    monthly_end_with
Bukkit                  2012-03 9                   431                 440
Bukkit                  2012-04 19                  438                 457
Bukkit                  2012-05 19                  455                 474
CodeIgniter             2012-03 15                  492                 507
CodeIgniter             2012-04 50                  506                 556
CodeIgniter             2012-05 19                  555                 574"),header=TRUE)
```

Reshape this here data:

```
test2 <- reshape(
    test[c("top100_repository_name","month","monthly_end_with")],
    idvar="top100_repository_name",
    timevar="month",
    direction="wide"
)
```

Fix the names

```
names(test2) <- gsub("monthly_end_with.","",names(test2))
```

Which looks like:

```
> test2
  top100_repository_name 2012-03 2012-04 2012-05
1                 Bukkit     440     457     474
4            CodeIgniter     507     556     574
```

Comment: +1, I usually try to give the base R approach when everyone else jumps on `dcast` from "reshape2", but you forced me this time.... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another pretty direct approach in base R. Use `xtabs()`:

```
xtabs(monthly_end_with ~ top100_repository_name + month, test)
#                       month
# top100_repository_name 2012-03 2012-04 2012-05
#            Bukkit          440     457     474
#            CodeIgniter     507     556     574

as.data.frame.matrix(
  xtabs(monthly_end_with ~ top100_repository_name + month, test))
#             2012-03 2012-04 2012-05
# Bukkit          440     457     474
# CodeIgniter     507     556     574
```

Or, as indicated by @thelatemail, there's `dcast` from the "reshape2" package which can be used as follows:

```
dcast(test, top100_repository_name ~ month, value.var="monthly_end_with")
#   top100_repository_name 2012-03 2012-04 2012-05
# 1                 Bukkit     440     457     474
# 2            CodeIgniter     507     556     574
```